# Cant post the data using Modal with Ajax in Razor Pages

Tags: html, css, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

This is the index file code:

```
 public IList<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGetAsync()
        {
            Employee = await _context.Employee.ToListAsync();
        }

        public JsonResult EmployeeList()
        {
            var data = _context.Employee.ToList();
            return new JsonResult(data);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult AddEmployee(Employee e)
        {
            var emp = new Employee()
            {
                Name = e.Name,
                Age = e.Age,
                Email = e.Email
            };
            _context.Employee.Add(emp);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return new JsonResult("Success!!!");
        }
```

Button to open Modal:

```
<button class="btn btn-info mb-3" id="btn1">Add Employee</button>
```

The Modal:

```
<!-- The Modal -->
<div class="modal Add-Emp">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" id="Name" autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Age" class="form-control" id="Age" autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control" id="Email" autocomplete="off"/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEmployee();">Save</button> I
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-default" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Js Code:

```
$("#btn1").click(function () {
        $(".Add-Emp").modal("show")
    })
function AddEmployee() { debugger
            var objData = { Name: $("#Name").val(), Age: $("#Age").val(), Email: $("#Email").val() }

            $.ajax({
                url: "Pages/Employees/Index/AddEmployee",
                type: "Post",
                data: objData,
                contentType: "application/xxx-www-form-url-encoded; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () { alert("Data Saved"); },
                error: function () { alert("Error!!!"); }
            })
        }
```

Modal opens on click But data does not get posted on clicking the save button it displays alert "Error!!!" defined in failure of ajax requestㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.You maybe not familiar with Razor Pages, Razor pages uses `OnGet` and `OnPost` to deal with the Http Get and Post request. If you need another Get or Post method in current PageModel, you need define the method name like: **OnGet**HandlerName or **OnPost**HandlerName.

2.If your `.cshtml.cs` file located like: `Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml.cs`, the request url should be:`/Employees/Index`. If you set the handler in your PageModel, the request url should be:`/Employees/Index?handler=xxx`.

3.For how to use Ajax in Razor Pages, Razor Pages enable anti-forgery token validation by default, so you need add this token to header in ajax.

If you use form in Razor Pages, it will default generate an input with token. If not, you need add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` manually.

**A whole working demo you could follow:**

Page(Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml):

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<button class="btn btn-info mb-3" id="btn1">Add Employee</button>
<div class="modal Add-Emp">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <!-- Modal Header -->
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Employee</h4>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal body -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="post">
                    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Name</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" class="form-control" id="Name" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Age</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Age" class="form-control" id="Age" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email" class="form-control" id="Email" autocomplete="off" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Modal footer -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="AddEmployee();">Save</button> I
                <button class="btn btn-danger btn-default" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $("#btn1").click(function () {
            $(".Add-Emp").modal("show")
        })
        function AddEmployee() {
            debugger
            var objData = { Name: $("#Name").val(), Age: $("#Age").val(), Email: $("#Email").val() }

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Employees/Index?handler=AddEmployee",
                type: "Post",
                data: JSON.stringify(objData), //change here...
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", //change here...
                headers: {
                    RequestVerificationToken:
                        $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()
                },   //add this....
                dataType: "json",
                success: function () { alert("Data Saved"); },
                error: function () { alert("Error!!!"); }
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

Pages/Employees/Index.cshtml.cs:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    //...
    public IList<Employee> Employee { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Employee = await _context.Employee.ToListAsync();
    }

    public JsonResult OnGetEmployeeList()
    {
        var data = _context.Employee.ToList();
        return new JsonResult(data);
    }

    public JsonResult OnPostAddEmployee([FromBody]Employee e)
    {
        var emp = new Employee()
        {
            Name = e.Name,
            Age = e.Age,
            Email = e.Email
        };
       
        return new JsonResult("Success!!!");
    }
}
```